# Is there any way to recover lost table data on sql server without backups?

Tags: recovery, azure-sql-database-v11

Unfortunately some tables are completely deleted with important data. The database is hosted on azure, but there is no back up for past 1 month as well.

Is there any way I can get the lost data?
The database is azure SQL v 11.

Answer (score 3):

You may actually be able to do a restore.  Grant Fritchey talked [about it here](http://www.scarydba.com/2016/01/11/restoring-a-database-in-azure/).

Basically if you go to the portal and look at the screen for the database there is a restore option.  Once you select it it will give you the oldest restore point available.  You can't overwrite your database but you can restore it to an alternate location.  It looks like you can only do this threw the GUI.  Once you have your alternate location restored you can get your data.

Since you can't do cross database queries you may have to find a third party software or download the data then upload it into the correct DB.

(There was something about being able to do cross database queries if you are in an elastic pool but I've never done that myself.)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but i dont know why in azure my restore options are the moment the database has been dropped from that time to current time.